# GoogleMapsPlot from openair not available?

Tags: openair

I would like to know why the GoogleMapsPlot function from the openair package is not available or at least I don't know why it doesn't appear in window.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://davidcarslaw.github.io/openair/news/index.html#openair-19-9 it looks like it's been deprecated as of openair 1.9 and is yet to be replaced.